# writing in file through shell script without using echo command

Tags: shell

I want to write some thing in a file through a shell script but inside the script I don't want to use the `echo` command to write in file.

Are there other ways to write in a file without using `echo` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots.

```
printf "foo" > somefile

cat > somefile << EOF
foo
EOF
```

bash allows:

```
cat > somefile <<< "foo"
```